# Converting arduino digitalRead to standard C

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to convert some arduino code to common C formatted code. I am stuck here however.

```
uint8_t pins[] = {13, 12, 11, 10, 8};   //PORTB (Will have 8 taken away from value to produce correct port number)
void loop() {  
if(!wait){

init_pin_state(1);                      // LED ON/OFF

randomSeed(analogRead(A0));                   // 
sequence[curLen] = pins[random(0,numpins)];
curLen++;
wait = true;
}
else{
init_pin_state(0)                             // Set pins to input
if(!btnDwn){                                  // 
  expRd = sequence[inputCount];               // Find the value we expect from the player

  for(int i = 0; i < numpins; i++){           // Loop through the all the pins
    if(pins[i]==expRd)                        
      continue;                               // Ignore the correct pin
    if(digitalRead(pins[i]) == HIGH){         // Is the buttong pressed
      lastInput = pins[i];
      resetFlag = true;                       // Set the resetFlag - this means you lost
      btnDwn = true;                          // This will prevent the program from doing the same thing over and over again
    }
  }     
if(PINB == (1 << (expRd-8)) && !btnDwn)        // The player pressed the right button
{
  inputTime = millis();                       // 
  lastInput = expRd;
  inputCount++;                               // The user pressed a (correct) button again
  btnDwn = true;                              

}else{
  if(btnDwn && PINB == (0 << lastInput-8)){  // Check if the player released the button
    btnDwn = false;
    _delay_ms(20);
    if(resetFlag){                              // If this was set to true up above, you lost
      DoLoseProcess();                          // So we do the losing sequence of events
    }
    else{
      if(inputCount == curLen){                 // Has the player finished repeating the sequence
        wait = false;                           // If so, this will make the next turn the program's turn
        inputCount = 0;                         // Reset the number of times that the player has pressed a button
        _delay_ms(900);
      }
    }
  }





}
```

I am trying to convert digitalRead to PIN variation with bitwise aspects. (eg PINB != 0b000000 for this case).
I have tried the above example but whenever i press the pushbutton connected to the pin the bottom if statement overides the top one. This code works in arduino though and I am unsure as to what the problem is.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're missing quite a bit of code there.  What's in this pins[i] array?  What about sequence and inputCount?  Please post a MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Have you researched how to read a pin state on low-level? A list of pin numbers will not be very helpful as this assignment is actually introduced in the arduino layer. For lowlevel stuff you need to look up the corresponding ports and their pins. The resulting code will not be portable between different atmega chips. The (general) `arduino` tag seems to be in contrast to what you want to do...

Comment: I forgot to add the line where i set all pins in PORTB to 0 to become inputs. Have added this in now, assumin this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that ever comes across this with the same problems.

```
digitalRead(pins[i]) == HIGH
```

I was trying to write it as

```
PINB == (1 << i)
```

Instead of the required

```
PINB == (1 << pins[i])
```

It was a stupid mistake tbh